AttributeError: 'FastAPI' object has no attribute 'database'
In the following code taken from a FastAPI tutorial, I am trying to set the app.database property via the asynccontextmanager and access it later in my route:
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import uvicorn
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
from pymongo import MongoClient
from routes.api import router as api_router
import logging


# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

config = dotenv_values(".env")


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    logging.info("Initializing MongoDB connection ...")
    app.mongodb_client = AsyncIOMotorClient(config["ATLAS_URI"])
    app.database = app.mongodb_client[config["DB_NAME"]]
    logging.info("Project connected to MongoDB database!")
    # dbHost = await connectToDatabase()
    # app.database = dbHost.pymongo_tutorial
    print("Project connected to the MongoDB database!")
    yield
    logging.info("Closing MongoDB connection ...")
    await app.mongodb_client.close()
    logging.info("Closed MongoDB connection")
    
app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.middleware("http")
async def check_database_access(request: Request, call_next):
    # Check if app.database is initialized
    if not hasattr(request.app, "database"):
        logging.warning("Attempted access to database before initialization")
    else:
        logging.info("Database access is safe")
    
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response

app.include_router(api_router)

if __name__ == '__main__': #this indicates that this a script to be run
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, log_level="error", reload = True)

But I am getting this error:
File "C:\Users\ekojo\Git\CRUD_python_mongo\src\rules\books.py", line 7, in get_collection_books
    return request.app.database["books"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'FastAPI' object has no attribute 'database'

This is my code in the books.py file:
def get_collection_books(request: Request):
    return request.app.database["books"]

In the original code this was the pattern used:
@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_db_client():
     app.mongodb_client = MongoClient(config["ATLAS_URI"])
     app.database = app.mongodb_client[config["DB_NAME"]]
     print("Project connected to the MongoDB database!")

@app.on_event("shutdown")
def shutdown_db_client():
    app.mongodb_client.close()

So basically I am trying to modify the code to use the asyncontextmanager and getting the stated error and after looking at the logs, it says I am trying to access the database property before it is set.
I have looked at my code, and I don't see how I can identify where this is happening.

You can identify where it is happening by reading the traceback: File "C:\Users\ekojo\Git\CRUD_python_mongo\src\rules\books.py", line 7, in get_collection_books. Below, it includes a snippet of your code and underlines the place where it is happening with ^^^. Is that what you wanted to know?
